# Possible to upgrade to latest Bluez using Mint 15 Olivia (Cinnamon)?

Tags: linux-mint, bluez

I'm using the latest version of Mint 15. I noticed that the Bluez version that is shipped with Mint 15 is 4.101 (http://www.bluez.org/bluez-4101/).

As you can see the release date is : 22nd June 2012.

I want the best possible bluetooth support and am currently experiencing numerous minor bugs during connection process / pairing / profile selection on my a2dp headphones.

I would like to upgrade to the latest version of Bluez (http://www.bluez.org/release-of-bluez-5-8/) version 5.8.

Is this possible , and if yes, how can this be done?